# How to approach "potential benefits to society of proposed research" question on a grant application for a pure math project?

Tags: research-process, mathematics, funding, research-proposal, supporting-information

I have been writing a grant proposal, where it is based in the UK. I almost did most of the application, but I have no idea for the following parts:

Benefits of Overseas Country: Describe any potential benefits to the overseas country and/or country of origin that will result from the proposed Fellowship. This may include supporting the development of a well-trained research community and promoting economic development and social welfare of the country through enhanced research and innovation capacity to benefit the wider society

Benefits of UK: Describe any potential benefits to the UK and UK research that will result from the proposed Fellowship

I am an early-stage researcher in pure math. To be honest, I see neither any benefits of my research to the economics nor to the UK. I would really appreciate it if one could give me some hints/examples. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you discuss this with your supervisor or line manager? What did they say?

Comment: @astronat : I am an independent researcher, and my supervisor doesn't help me.

Comment: @Adam Maybe you don't have a line manager now, but what about the person who will be your line manager at the host institution if you succeed in getting the fellowship funding?  Are they helping?

Comment: "development of a well-trained research community"  That's your answer.

Comment: @DanielHatton I asked him and he said I should do them myself.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist could you explain a bit more?

Comment: I would suggest you start by thinking about the "supporting the development of a well-trained research community".  In the US, we have to do something similar for NSF grants.  This is called "broader impacts."  Try looking online for advice about writing about broader impacts to get concrete ideas.

Comment: @Kimball : Thank you for your useful comment.

Comment: @Kimball : Do you have any idea what is difference between Benefits of Overseas Country and of UK? because my answer is the same for both of them